# RESOLVED sleep methods hang the program threads in C pthreads (race condition, it had nothing to do with sleep)

Tags: c, pthreads

**I created a C program with pthreads, and it works perfectly until I add any sort of sleep function, whether it's be  sleep() or usleep() or  nanosleep().**

Yes, before you ask, I know usleep() is deprecated and I have copied the correct usage of nanosleep() from another stackoferflow post, but even sleep() doesn't work.

The code (the critical section is in the "clients" thread, at line 99):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LIBERA 0
#define OCCUPATA 1
#define TUTTE_SEDIE_OCCUPATE -1
#define OCCUPATA_DA_BARBIERE -2

#define NRCLIENTI 10
#define NRSEDIE 5

pthread_mutex_t poltrona_m, dorme_m, get_sedia_m, occupa_sedia_m;
sem_t sem;
int sedia_taglio = LIBERA, sedia_attesa[NRSEDIE];

void init_attr(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NRSEDIE; i++)
        sedia_attesa[i] = LIBERA;
    sem_init(&sem, 0, NRSEDIE);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&poltrona_m);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&dorme_m);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&get_sedia_m);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&occupa_sedia_m);
}

int my_sleep(long millis) {
    struct timespec req, rem;

    if (millis > 999) {
        req.tv_sec = (int) (millis / 1000);
        req.tv_nsec = (millis - ((long) req.tv_sec * 1000)) * 1000000;
    } else {
        req.tv_sec = 0;
        req.tv_nsec = millis * 1000000;
    }

    return nanosleep(&req, &rem);
}

int get_sedia_libera() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&get_sedia_m);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NRSEDIE; i++)
        if (sedia_attesa[i] == LIBERA)
            return i;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&get_sedia_m);
    return TUTTE_SEDIE_OCCUPATE;
}

int occupa_sedia(int index) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&occupa_sedia_m);
    int result;
    if(sedia_attesa[index] == LIBERA){
        sedia_attesa[index] = OCCUPATA;
        result = 1;
    }else
        result = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&occupa_sedia_m);
    return result;
}

void libera_sedia(int index) {
    sedia_attesa[index] = LIBERA;
}

void *barbiere(void *arg) {
    while (1)
    {
        if (sedia_taglio == OCCUPATA) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&poltrona_m);
            sedia_taglio = LIBERA;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&poltrona_m);
        }

        if (get_sedia_libera() == 0 && sedia_taglio == LIBERA) {
            sedia_taglio = OCCUPATA_DA_BARBIERE;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&dorme_m);
            printf("[BARBIERE] il barbiere dorme...\n");
        }
    }
}

void *cliente(void *arg) {
    int n;
    int *id = (void *)arg;

    while (1)
    {
        if (sedia_taglio == LIBERA || sedia_taglio == OCCUPATA_DA_BARBIERE) {

            pthread_mutex_lock(&poltrona_m);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&dorme_m);
            sedia_taglio = OCCUPATA;
            printf("----[CLIENTE] Cliente \"%d\" si taglia i capelli!\n", *id);
            my_sleep(2000);
            sedia_taglio = LIBERA;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&poltrona_m);
            pthread_exit(0);

        } else {
            n = get_sedia_libera();
            if(n == TUTTE_SEDIE_OCCUPATE) {
                fprintf(stderr, "----[CLIENTE] No posti liberi cliente \"%d\" lascia il negozio\n", *id);
                pthread_exit((void *)1);
            } else {
                sem_wait(&sem);
                n = get_sedia_libera();
                if(occupa_sedia(n) && n != TUTTE_SEDIE_OCCUPATE){
                    printf("----[CLIENTE] Cliente \"%d\" aspetta su sedia #%d\n", *id, n+1);
                    while (sedia_taglio != LIBERA);
                    sem_post(&sem);
                    libera_sedia(n);
                } else {
                    sem_post(&sem);
                    fprintf(stderr, "----[CLIENTE] No posti liberi cliente \"%d\" lascia il negozio\n", *id);
                    pthread_exit(0);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    init_attr();

    int i, id[NRCLIENTI];
    pthread_t barbiere_thread, cliente_thread[NRCLIENTI];

    if(pthread_create(&barbiere_thread, NULL, barbiere, NULL ) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "[MAIN] Error creating \"barber\" thread!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("[MAIN] thread \"barber\" creato\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < NRCLIENTI; ++i) {
        id[i] = i+1;
        printf("[MAIN] thread \"client %d\" creato\n", id[i]);
        if(pthread_create(&cliente_thread[i], NULL, cliente, &id[i]) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "[MAIN] Error creating \"client %d\" thread!\n", id[i]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NRCLIENTI; i++){
        pthread_join(cliente_thread[i], NULL);
        printf("[MAIN]Joined client \"%d\"\n", i+1);
    }

    //il programma non finira mai se sta ad aspettare un thread con un ciclo while(1) al suo interno
    //senza condizioni di break!!!
    pthread_join(barbiere_thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Normal execution(this is how the program *should* work):**

```
[MAIN] thread "client 1" creato
[BARBIERE] il barbiere dorme...
hey
[MAIN] thread "client 2" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "1" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 3" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "2" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 4" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "3" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 5" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "4" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 6" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "5" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 7" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "6" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 8" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "7" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 9" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "8" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 10" creato
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "9" si taglia i capelli!
----<<<<<<<<<<<<[CLIENTE] Cliente "10" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "1"
[MAIN]Joined client "2"
[MAIN]Joined client "3"
[MAIN]Joined client "4"
[MAIN]Joined client "5"
[MAIN]Joined client "6"
[MAIN]Joined client "7"
[MAIN]Joined client "8"
[MAIN]Joined client "9"
[MAIN]Joined client "10"
```

**Execution with any sleep method, sleep(1), nanosleep() with 1 second or 100k microsecond usleep()**
*but I don't take usleep() into consideration because* a) *its deprecated and * b) *you cant put more or equal than 1million microseconds; usleep(1000000) is NOT valid*

```
[MAIN] thread "client 1" creato
[BARBIERE] il barbiere dorme...
[MAIN] thread "client 2" creato
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "1" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN] thread "client 3" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 4" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 5" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 6" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 7" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 8" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 9" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 10" creato
[MAIN]Joined client "1"
```

**As you can see, the threads just... stall. I waited with the terminal open for 5 minutes, and still, nothing changed.**
The strangest thing is that if I run this in windows IntelliJ Clion using MinGW, the sleep() functions seem totally ignored (the program executes itself in a fraction of a second)!

Thanks for reading through all of this, I hope we can find a solution and I'd be grateful for any help I get!

Comment: Please use uppercase for constants! This is pain to read.

Comment: Your are trying to use locks to provide mutual exclusive access to shared variables, but you don't. You use them around writes, but not around reads. Bad.

Comment: One of the first think you might do is `pthread_mutex_unlock(&dorme_m);` on a mutex that isn't locked.  It's not a problem in of itself, but it highlights a race condition. You could call unlock just before the barber calls lock. A cond var would make more sense here, but a mutex could also work if done correctly.

Comment: Hey @ikegami , thank you so much for helping me! First off I capitalized the macros, sorry for that!
So you think the problem isn't within the sleep() function but rather my sloppy code due to my poor programming knowledge, especially about pthreads?
**I'm trying to eliminate any race condition, could you tell me where you saw that I was reading a variable without locks?**
Also may I ask you if I used the `dorme_m` mutex incorrectly? Maybe I should use the same mutex for get_sedia_libera() and occupa_sedia()?

Comment: You also talked about stuff like volatile and conditional variables, they seem like advanced topics, nevertheless I'm going to try and learn about them! thanks!
P.S. If you want to I can rewrite the code in english so that you can understand it better; Let me know!

Comment: Re "*So you think the problem isn't within the sleep() function*", I'm not saying anything either way on that. The man page does say it's not thread-safe

Comment: as I say in my answer *sleep* blocks all the process and not only the current thread

Comment: Re "*You also talked about stuff like volatile*", Ignore that. (Comment deleted.) Properly use of mutex instead.

Comment: Re "*You also talked about stuff like volatile*", Cond vars are a basic element of multithreading. They are used when you want to wait until something changes, e.g. wait until `vget_sedia_libera() == 0 && sedia_taglio == LIBERA` becomes false

Comment: @ikegami thanks, I feel like cond variables could really come in handy!
Also I currently use nanosleep() which should be thread safe.
Like you and @bruno said, the problem lied within the `dorme_m` mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You creates deadlock because you have race condition between threads.

Moving `pthread_mutex_t poltrona_m, dorme_m, get_sedia_m, occupa_sedia_m;`
 at global scope, adding these verbose functions:

```
const char * whoIam()
{
  if (pthread_self() == barbiere_thread)
    return "barbiere";

  for (int i = 0; i != NRCLIENTI; ++i) {
    if (pthread_self() == cliente_thread[i]) {
      static char str[NRCLIENTI][64];

      sprintf(str[i], "cliente %d", i+1); /* done several times but whatever */
      return str[i];
    }
  } 

  return "unknown-thread";
}

const char * whoIsMutex(pthread_mutex_t * m)
{
  if (m == &poltrona_m)
    return "poltrona";
  if (m == &dorme_m)
    return "dorme";
  if (m == &get_sedia_m)
    return "sedia";
  if (m == &occupa_sedia_m)
    return "occupa_sedia";
  return "unknown-mutex";
}

void my_pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t * m)
{
  printf("%s unlock %s\n", whoIam(), whoIsMutex(m));
  pthread_mutex_unlock(m);
}

void my_pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t * m)
{
  printf("%s want to lock %s\n", whoIam(), whoIsMutex(m));
  pthread_mutex_lock(m);
  printf("%s locked %s\n", whoIam(), whoIsMutex(m));
}
```

and using `my_pthread_mutex_lock` and `my_pthread_mutex_unlock` out of `init_attr` the execution can be :

```
[MAIN] thread "barber" creato

[MAIN] thread "client 1" creato
barbiere want to lock sedia
barbiere locked sedia
barbiere want to lock dorme
barbiere locked dorme
cliente 1 want to lock poltrona
cliente 1 locked poltrona
cliente 1 unlock dorme           <<< does nothing because does not have it
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "1" si taglia i capelli!
[BARBIERE] il barbiere dorme...
barbiere want to lock poltrona   <<< wait while get by client 1
[MAIN] thread "client 2" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 3" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 4" creato
cliente 2 want to lock sedia
[MAIN] thread "client 5" creato
cliente 4 want to lock sedia
[MAIN] thread "client 6" creato
cliente 3 want to lock sedia
[MAIN] thread "client 7" creato
cliente 6 want to lock sedia
cliente 5 want to lock sedia
[MAIN] thread "client 8" creato
cliente 7 want to lock sedia
[MAIN] thread "client 9" creato
cliente 8 want to lock sedia
[MAIN] thread "client 10" creato
cliente 9 want to lock sedia
cliente 10 want to lock sedia
cliente 1 unlock poltrona     <<< finally unlock poltrona
barbiere locked poltrona      <<< wake up
barbiere unlock poltrona
barbiere want to lock sedia   <<< dead because get by itself
[MAIN]Joined client "1"
```

Adding `my_sleep(1000);` before `sedia_taglio = occupata;` in *cliente* helps to not have the race condition :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ gcc -Wall t.c -lpthread
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
[MAIN] thread "barber" creato

[MAIN] thread "client 1" creato
[BARBIERE] il barbiere dorme...
[MAIN] thread "client 2" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 3" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 4" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 5" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 6" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 7" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 8" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 9" creato
[MAIN] thread "client 10" creato
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "1" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "1"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "3" si taglia i capelli!
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "2" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "2"
[MAIN]Joined client "3"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "4" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "4"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "5" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "5"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "6" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "6"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "7" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "7"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "8" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "8"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "9" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "9"
----[CLIENTE] Cliente "10" si taglia i capelli!
[MAIN]Joined client "10"
```

Out of that, about the way to *sleep*, the function *sleep* blocks all the process, contrarily to *usleep* and *nanosleep*.

---

Here a proposal without race condition, nor making assumption on the *mutex* implementation (no undefined behavior).

There is only one *mutex* to protect datas consistency and for the conditions, I also use it to protect printing.

There are seats to wait, and one used to cut hairs. To manage clients in order of arrival they get a ticket having a number, when there is no free seat at all a client cannot get a ticket and will retry later. The number of the ticket of the client to have hairs cut is given by *CurrentTicket* (as a screen client read) and the signal *NextClient* is produced (as a beep) to allow clients to check if their turn comes. The number of the ticket in the distributor is managed by *LastTicket*. The signal *HelloBarber* is sent by a client when he reaches the barber and may be wake up him. The barber sleeps when there is no client.

I use a random time limited to 5 seconds for the delay used by a client to (re)try to get a place, and the barber cut hairs of a client in a random time limited to 3 seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NCLIENT 10
#define NSEAT 5 /* seats to wait */

unsigned int Seed;
int Nseat = NSEAT  + 1; /* add 1 to have seat to cut hairs */
int CurrentTicket = 0;
int LastTicket = 0;

pthread_mutex_t Mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t NextClient = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t HelloBarber = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

/* return -1 is no seat, else ticket number */
int getTicket()
{
  int result;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
  if (Nseat == 0)
    result = -1;
  else {
    Nseat -= 1;
    result = ++LastTicket;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);

  return result;
}

void randomSleep(int max)
{
  int millis = rand_r(&Seed) % (max * 1000);
  struct timespec req, rem;

  if (millis > 999) {
    req.tv_sec = (int) (millis / 1000);
    req.tv_nsec = (millis - ((long) req.tv_sec * 1000)) * 1000000;
  } else {
    req.tv_sec = 0;
    req.tv_nsec = millis * 1000000;
  }

  nanosleep(&req, &rem);
}

void * client(void * arg)
{
  int id = *((int *) arg);
  int ticket;
  int justArrived = 1;

  while (randomSleep(5), ((ticket = getTicket()) == -1)) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
    printf("----[CLIENT] Client \"%d\" no place, will try again later\n", id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
  printf("----[CLIENT] Client \"%d\" got ticket number %d\n", id, ticket);

  while (ticket != CurrentTicket) {
    printf("----[CLIENT] Client \"%d\" not my turn\n", id);
    if (justArrived) {
      justArrived = 0;
      printf("----[CLIENT] Client \"%d\" seat to wait\n", id);
    }
    pthread_cond_wait(&NextClient, &Mutex);
  }
  printf("----[CLIENT] Client \"%d\" my turn\n", id);
  if (justArrived)
    printf("----[CLIENT] Client \"%d\" do not need to seat to wait\n", id);

  pthread_cond_signal(&HelloBarber);

  pthread_cond_wait(&NextClient, &Mutex);
  printf("----[CLIENT] Client \"%d\" done for me\n", id);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);

  return NULL;
}

void * barber(void * dummy)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);

  puts("[BARBER] ready");
  CurrentTicket = 1;
  pthread_cond_signal(&NextClient);

  for (;;) {
    printf("[BARBER] screen indicates ticket %d\n", CurrentTicket);

    int sleep = (Nseat == NSEAT + 1);

    if (sleep)
      puts("[BARBER] no client, time to sleep");

    pthread_cond_wait(&HelloBarber, &Mutex); /* in all cases to be sure next client had time to see his turn */

    if (sleep)
      puts("[BARBER] woken up by a client");
    puts("[BARBER] cutting hairs");

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
    randomSleep(3); /* time to cut hairs of current client */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);

    puts("[BARBER] haircut done");
    Nseat += 1;
    CurrentTicket += 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&NextClient);
  }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t barber_thread, client_thread[NCLIENT];
  int i, id[NCLIENT];

  Seed = time(NULL);

  if (pthread_create(&barber_thread, NULL, barber, NULL ) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "[MAIN] Error creating \"barber\" thread!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
  if (CurrentTicket == 0) {
    /* wait barber ready */
    pthread_cond_wait(&NextClient, &Mutex);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);

  for (i = 0; i < NCLIENT; ++i) {
    id[i] = i+1;
    if (pthread_create(&client_thread[i], NULL, client, &id[i]) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "[MAIN] Error creating \"client %d\" thread!\n", id[i]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < NCLIENT; i++) {
    pthread_join(client_thread[i], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
    printf("[MAIN] Joined client \"%d\"\n", i+1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and example of execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -Wall barber.c  -lpthread
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
[BARBER] ready
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 1
[BARBER] no client, time to sleep
----[CLIENT] Client "7" got ticket number 1
----[CLIENT] Client "7" my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "7" do not need to seat to wait
[BARBER] woken up by a client
[BARBER] cutting hairs
----[CLIENT] Client "6" got ticket number 2
----[CLIENT] Client "6" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "6" seat to wait
----[CLIENT] Client "5" got ticket number 3
----[CLIENT] Client "5" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "5" seat to wait
----[CLIENT] Client "1" got ticket number 4
----[CLIENT] Client "1" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "1" seat to wait
----[CLIENT] Client "3" got ticket number 5
----[CLIENT] Client "3" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "3" seat to wait
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 2
----[CLIENT] Client "7" done for me
----[CLIENT] Client "3" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "1" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "6" my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "5" not my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
----[CLIENT] Client "9" got ticket number 6
----[CLIENT] Client "9" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "9" seat to wait
----[CLIENT] Client "8" got ticket number 7
----[CLIENT] Client "8" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "8" seat to wait
----[CLIENT] Client "4" no place, will try again later
----[CLIENT] Client "2" no place, will try again later
----[CLIENT] Client "10" no place, will try again later
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 3
----[CLIENT] Client "8" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "5" my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "9" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "1" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "6" done for me
[BARBER] cutting hairs
----[CLIENT] Client "3" not my turn
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 4
----[CLIENT] Client "9" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "1" my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "3" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "5" done for me
----[CLIENT] Client "8" not my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 5
----[CLIENT] Client "8" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "1" done for me
[MAIN] Joined client "1"
----[CLIENT] Client "9" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "3" my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
----[CLIENT] Client "10" got ticket number 8
----[CLIENT] Client "10" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "10" seat to wait
----[CLIENT] Client "2" got ticket number 9
----[CLIENT] Client "2" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "2" seat to wait
----[CLIENT] Client "4" got ticket number 10
----[CLIENT] Client "4" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "4" seat to wait
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 6
----[CLIENT] Client "2" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "3" done for me
----[CLIENT] Client "4" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "8" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "9" my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "10" not my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 7
----[CLIENT] Client "2" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "9" done for me
----[CLIENT] Client "4" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "8" my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
----[CLIENT] Client "10" not my turn
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 8
----[CLIENT] Client "10" my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
----[CLIENT] Client "2" not my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "8" done for me
----[CLIENT] Client "4" not my turn
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 9
----[CLIENT] Client "10" done for me
----[CLIENT] Client "2" my turn
----[CLIENT] Client "4" not my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 10
----[CLIENT] Client "2" done for me
----[CLIENT] Client "4" my turn
[BARBER] cutting hairs
[MAIN] Joined client "2"
[MAIN] Joined client "3"
[BARBER] haircut done
[BARBER] screen indicates ticket 11
[BARBER] no client, time to sleep
----[CLIENT] Client "4" done for me
[MAIN] Joined client "4"
[MAIN] Joined client "5"
[MAIN] Joined client "6"
[MAIN] Joined client "7"
[MAIN] Joined client "8"
[MAIN] Joined client "9"
[MAIN] Joined client "10"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Hey, I just did what you said and it fixed the program! Then again, I still don't understand *why* it fixed it... if you have more time on your hands could you explain more in detail what happened?
Also if I understood correctly when a mutex gets unlocked twice it can cause problems(undefined behaviour). Is that true?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PtContact my first version was finally wrong, I edited my answer, reread it please

Comment: in your case you use *fast* mutexes `pthread_mutex_unlock` forces the *mutex* to be free even if it was not get and also allows to lock and unlock in different threads which is in theory  forbidden. But this is implementation dependent so yes undefined behavior. I all the linux I used to lock and unlock in two different threads is ok, and to be frank I use that behavior ;-)

Comment: OH I GOT IT! Thats why it worked in windows but not in my Linux virtual machine

Comment: The only problem now is that there is no actual concurrency; no waiting chairs are used, the clients manage to get to the grooming chair without having to wait :/

Comment: @PtContact perhaps also your problems comes from your use of variables and mutex, and it is more adapted to use variables and conditions (also using mutex but whatever) I mean `pthread_cond_xxx` For me one thing is sure : to use several  mutex in 'nested' way is the best way to create deadlock, do not do that

Comment: Thanks @bruno , I understand that I should be using more than mutexes for this program and I have also implemented mutex in an unsafe way, if you have spare time on your hands and you feel like it could you improve my program so that it actually works? That is if its easy to improve, or it's so bad it should be completely rewritten...

Comment: Hey @bruno , I was just about to tell you about how the program should work, but you already created another program that works perfectly! It's just what I wanted, even more that what I needed lol! Thanks so much for this, right now I'm studying the source code to see how it works (there are some things new to me) ***Anyways thank you so much for helping me!*** You guys at StackOverflow are so nice, have a wonderful day! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215117/discussion-between-ptcontact-and-bruno).